# Is there any way to wait for alsa events through epoll mechanism?

Tags: c, alsa, epoll, libalsa

I fetch alsa device fd by fd field of struct pollfd structure filled by snd_pcm_poll_descriptors...
But when it comes to "demangle" event comming from epoll_wait, snd_pcm_poll_descriptors_revents
which is no help since only struct pollfd fits to it's arguments.

Comment: I was thinking about fork to have a separate process sending data recieved from a pipe but I'm not sure about read completion notification through pipe on parent process side. I mean, being notified that pipe is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an epoll notification about a file descriptor, set the corresponding bit(s) in the `revents` field of the original `struct pollfd`. Then you can call `snd_pcm_poll_descriptors()`.